# How to disable ampersand encoding in {{ attributes }}

Tags: theming

Is it possible to disable the ampersand encoding when rendering `<div {{ attributes }}>` in a hook (preferred) or Twig?

Background:
Drupal by default escapes ampersands `&` into `&amp;`. This usually is a good thing, but I've the edge case where I need to render one-off TailwindCSS class names like `[&_.child-of-this-div]:text-red`. Looks weird, but is actually a completely valid CSS class name.

But due the ampersand encoding, the rendered output now looks like `<div class="[&amp;_.child-of-this-div]:text-red">`, which by CSS rules is now a completely different class name, and Tailwind's parser therefore no longer "sees" the real class name `[&_.child-of-this-div]:text-red`.

Already tried, did not work:

- Backslash escaping `[\&_.child-of-this-div]:text-red` (still incorrect output)
- using CSS symbol encoding `[\000026_.child-of-this-div]:text-red` (does not work with Tailwind's parser).
- using the raw filter: `{{ attributes|raw }}` (still incorrect output)

Answer (score 0):

The combination of both, `|replace` **and** `|raw`, does remove the encoding.

```
<div {{ attributes|replace({'&amp;': '&'})|raw }}>
```

I needed data-attributes to remain untouched, the closest I got so far is

```
<div class="{{ attributes.class|replace({'&amp;': '&'})|raw }}" {{ attributes|without('class') }}>
```

but this is tedious and unsafe.

I'm still looking for something that does not use `|raw`, so I leave the question open.